# PHP can't extract out all the data from database when running on a server

Tags: php

Hi I am doing a google map that shows traffic conditions of ExpressWay. All the data are stored on phpmyadmin. I have `20,000KB` data in my database and what I do is extract the data according to the date. It supposed to show traffic condition of `0:00 to 23:59 hr`.
It was working properly on my localhost where I created my project. Now I have put it on server and the map can only show up to an hour or less than that.
But the program continue to run without showing 24hr data. 
Is there any restriction while running on a server? Any way to fix this?

Thanks in advance!!

**Here is the link http://nypinfo.net/VisualTraffic/15feb.php and http://nypinfo.net/VisualTraffic/16feb.php..
I am using the same code but 15Feb will stop at 1 hour interval and 16Feb will stop at 5hr while both supposed to run till 24hr.**

```
var locations = <?php echo json_encode($array); ?>;

var mapOptions = {
zoom: 13, minZoom: 12, maxZoom: 14,
center: singapore,
mapTypeControlOptions: 
{mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, MY_MAPTYPE_ID]},
mapTypeId: MY_MAPTYPE_ID};

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),  mapOptions);

var myVar = setInterval(function(){myTimer()},0.01);

var ii = 0;
var maxRecord = locations.length;
function myTimer() {var t1 = (locations[ii]['CreateDate']);
var t2 = t1.substring(11,13);

if (parseInt(t2) == count) {
start_latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[ii]['LocationA'],locations[ii]['LocationA1']);
end_latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[ii]['LocationB'],locations[ii]['LocationB1']);

roadCoordinates = [start_latlng,end_latlng];

document.getElementById("timehr").innerHTML = "&nbsp;" + locations[ii]['CreateDate'].substring(11,13) + "&nbsp;";

document.getElementById("timeminsec").innerHTML = "&nbsp;"+ locations[ii]['CreateDate'].substring(14,19) + "&nbsp;";

document.getElementById("datez").innerHTML = "Date of Traffic Visualization: " +locations[ii]['CreateDate'].substring(0,10);
```

Comment: Hi I added some codes to my questions. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No there's no restriction. Something is wrong with your code (or there is no data spanning more than 24 hours)

Answer (score 0):

Show us Your query and example row in db. Also, check if MySQL and PHP on server are configured to run with the same time zone settings - it's quite common issue

Comment: Hi I added some codes to my questions and also the link to my website. can't post my database screen shot as I don't have enough reputation. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You should really check timezone settings. As @Hajime said, run echo date in php and then try add some entry to db - then check if times/dates are equal

Comment: I checked and changed my timezone settings. It's still the same. Any other possibilites? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should check your timezone. You can use this to check your current time

```
<?
    echo date("d/m/Y H:i:s");
?>
```

If your time is not correct with server time then you can set it by using this

```
date_default_timezone_set(<Your time zone>);
```